# simplest way to have Express serve a default page?

Tags: node.js, express

I'm using this to have Node.js/Express setup as a rudimentary web server - it just serves a set of static pages without any other processing. I'd like it to always serve /default.html when a browser fetches the site without any filename.

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.configure(function(){
  app.use(express.bodyParser());
});

app.use(express.logger());

app.use(express.static(__dirname ));

app.listen(port, function() {
  console.log("Listening on " + port);
});
```

I've tried using res.sendfile and res.redirect, but without much success; I'm obviously missing something as I end up with a 'has no method' error.

What would you say is the simplest way of achieving my goal?

Comment: Are you trying to send default.html when a request is made on your server's root ( '/' ) or everytime you can't find a static file to serve ?

Comment: the former, though the latter would have been fine as well.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You could do something like this. Assuming its an html file that is relative to the .js file:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.sendfile('default.html', { root: __dirname + "/relative_path_of_file" } );
});
```

Comment: most excellent, thank you. I put this (after editing /relative_path_of_file, of course) right before app.listen and it does exactly what I wanted. I'm still not sure why my other attempts were failing, but this is a good solution.

Answer (score 38):

I looked briefly for the best practices for serving a public folder and specifying the default page to serve.  After reviewing the 'Express middleware' documentation, my solution looks like the following,

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

var options = {
  index: "coming-soon.html"
};

app.use('/', express.static('app', options));

var server = app.listen(8081, function () {
  var host = server.address().address;
  var port = server.address().port;

  console.log('my app is listening at http://%s:%s', host, port);
});
```

Comment: tl;dr `app.use('/', express.static('app', {index: "coming-soon.html"}));`

Answer (score 5):

It's weird that no one mentioned redirection.

```
app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.redirect('/default.html');
});
```

This -of course- assumes that you have your 'default.html' at the public path.
You can set your public path by using:

```
app.use(express.static(relative_path_to_project_root));
```

Answer (score 1):

I've added my own variation with some extra "meat" on it to demonstrate how you can even include routing. I put all the following code in a file called "routes.js":

```
var express = require('express'),
    painting = require('./controllers').Painting,
    gallery = require('./controllers').Gallery;

module.exports.initialize = function(appSvr, router) {
    router.get('/paintings', painting.list);
    router.get('/galleries', gallery.list);

    appSvr.use('/', router);
    appSvr.use('/', express.static(__dirname + '/../public', { index: 'index.html' }));
};
```

I then call this file in my "configure.js" file that will be required in my "server.js" file:

```
var routes = require('./routes'),
    express = require('express'),
    bodyParser = require('body-parser');

module.exports = function(appSvr) {
    appSvr.use(bodyParser.urlencoded());
    appSvr.use(bodyParser.json());
    routes.initialize(appSvr, new express.Router());

    return appSvr;
};
```

I haven't seen how best to handle routing, but this code seems to work for me.

Would love some feedback!

Comment: `{ index: 'index.html' }` saved my day